# Removing vertical borderlines from the datatable

Tags: javascript, css, datatable, border, webix

I wish I could remove vertical borders between the columns in the Webix datatable. The point is that `borderless:true` property used for the borders between controls, but not for the inner borderlines.

Maybe someone knows how to do this? 
The code is pretty simple:
Here's a [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/b567199b) of a simple datatable.

```
webix.ui({  
 view:"datatable",     
 data:mydata, 
 columns:[
   {id:"id", header:"#"},
   {id:"title", header:"Title", fillspace:true},
   {id:"artist",  header:"Artist"},
   {id:"album",  header:"Album"},
   {id:"year", header:"Year"}
 ],
 //autoconfig:true,    
});
```

And here's another question. Should it be done in the column properties or I can preserve `autoconfig:true`? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe:

CSS

```
.webix_dtable .webix_cell {
    border-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this in your css file (or inside style tags):

```
td {
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

this will remove vertical borderlines on each cell of your table and draw a border on bottom.

P.S: if you want to do that exactly on that snippet, you can go to line 253 of file flat.css which is this:

```
border-right: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
```

and make it comment, or override it somewhere else like this:

```
.webix_column > div {
   border-right-width: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation!